# How do I stop my PC from autoplaying media files present on my SD card on my Android Phone?

Tags: 12.10, android, sd-card, autoplay

How do I stop my PC from autoplaying media files present on my SD card on my Android Phone? Whenever my USB linkage cord between my PC and my phone is wobbled just a little bit my Ubuntu 12.10 tries to play all the files on my SD card (like audio and picture files) how do I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up System Settings and click "Details". Under removable media set the drop down menus under music player and photos to "Do nothing."

Comment: Yes I open up nautilus and then find the files on my SD card and click on them to play them.

Answer (score 5):

Click on power button
[image: power button]

Click on system settings

[image: system settings]

Click on details
[image: Details]

Click on Removable Media; then you could;

- Check the box to "Never prompt..."
  [image: boxcheck]

or

- Set the drop down menus under "music player" and "photos" to "Do nothing."

Maybe using a newer/different cable to try and stop the problem of device/s being detected but then disconnecting and reconnecting if moved at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when the cable is wiggled, it is re-detected. How about just disabling autoplay?

To disable autoplay:

```
 gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount_open False
```

To enable autoplay:

```
 gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount_open True
```

Comment: This didn't work, it still autoplayed.